# ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload not working when updatepanel in same page is triggered

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have the following situation:

A master page with a usercontrol inside an update panel that triggers each minute by a timer.
In a content page i have an `ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload` which have the functionality drag and drop, at page load the upload control is working fine but after the first trigger on the update panel the control stops working.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try [AsyncFileUpload](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/AsyncFileUpload/AsyncFileUpload.aspx)

Comment: It's too complicate to find out what's wrong without source code.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate the issue and solve it by placing the `AjaxFileUpload` control inside of the `ContentTemplate` node of an `UpdatePanel`.

If you place it in its own `UpdatePanel`, make sure the `UpdateMode` is set to "Always". If you want it to be "Conditional", you'll need to have it be updated with the trigger in some way.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload2" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```